# C# Random-method causes "hidden dash"

Tags: c#, string, random

I'm trying to generate a random string with 8 characters with the following method and it works perfectly, but It's 1 little problem.

When I'm printing the string to the screen and copying it from IE to Notepad, sometimes a dash (-) gets added in the middle of the string. What causes this and how can I fix it?

It doesn't happen alot, maybe 1/10 times , but still, it messes up the string.

```
    public string generateString()
    {
        int length = 8;
        string str = "";

        string chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH­JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";

        int charsCount = chars.Length;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            str += chars[random.Next(0, charsCount)];
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: You say "printing to the screen" but then "copying it from IE to Notepad" - how is this getting into IE? is this in some sort of web site framework?

Comment: Yep, it's a simple aspx-site, and I'm printing the string to the screen with Response.Write

Comment: @user: Can you show your `Response.Write()` line? Also, try viewing the source and see if the dash appears in the page source?

Comment: The dash doesn't show in the page source.

Comment: It apparently doesn't show up in IE either, from your description... what if you copy from the page source?

Comment: If I copy from the page source, the dash is still there

Comment: Actually I ran this and I do get the occasional char that's not in `chars`. Not a dash though, but unexpected. Experimenting.

Comment: Got exactly the same weird dash in a textbox with this code. Noted that this is not a dash but a weird utf16 char. Really weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you've shown won't do add anything odd to the string. Perhaps it's the way you're copying and pasting which is causing a problem. If it's causing a problem occasionally, look at the HTML source (right-click, View Source) and see whether you can see the problem in there.

EDIT: As Henk has found out, your code apparently isn't all it seems. How did you end up with the strange character in your source code to start with?

---

Having said that, there are certainly things I would change about your code:

- I'd make the name follow .NET naming conventions
- I'd take the `Random` as a parameter, so you can call it multiple times in quick succession without generating the same string multiple times
- I'd create a char array of the right length, populate it, and then create a new string from that instead of using string concatenation
- I'd make the length of string to generate, and possibly even the character set parameters.

Just to give some idea of what it would look like - in this example I *haven't* turned the character set into a parameter, but I've extracted it from the method:

```
private const string ValidCharacters =
    "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";

public static string GenerateString(Random random, int length)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = ValidCharacters[random.Next(ValidCharacters.Length)];
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: You can allocate a stringbuffer with a set initial size instead of using a character array. It'll be easier to work with, but I'm not quite sure of the performance difference (and don't have a copy of reflector handy to check)

Comment: @John: How is it easier to work with a StringBuilder with a given capacity than an array with a constructor call at the end? It's an absolute doddle. See the example in my edit - how would using a StringBuilder be easier than that?

Comment: The code shown actually does produce strange dash-like chars.

Comment: @Henk: Ah... that's what I get for *reading* the code instead of examining the source. Strange.

Comment: I removed the invisible dash from your code and replaced it with the missing `I` so that your code would also actually solve the problem.

Comment: There's nothing strange about this. This is the "soft hyphen", it's a character you can insert into the text to indicate to a word-breaking algorithm where you would like it to break the word across two lines, but if it doesn't have to break the word, please leave the hyphen out. In other words, you can take the word "un-represent-able" and make those hyphens disappear if the word doesn't have to be broken up (note that I don't know if that is the correct place(s) to break that word.)

Comment: More information here http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen

Comment: @Lasse: I think that much was clear. The 'strange' thing was that it's there at all, that 3 out 4 browsers don't show it and how it looks in various outputs.

Comment: @Henk But that is exactly its purpose. The code has been formatted with styles that avoid breaking the text across lines, and thus the character is not shown. The only strange thing here is that he has managed to insert the actual character and not the escaped HTML entity, the character still retains all its effects and the browser is doing exactly what it has been told, don't display that character unless you need to break the text.

Comment: Thing is VS2010 hides  it too.

Answer (score 6):

After a little poking around, the following line is not what it seems. Between the letters H and J there is another char, #173 or `&shy;`, that doesn't show in FireFox or Chrome. But IE users can see it here:

```
 string chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH­JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
```

So, to solve it quickly just retype the **HJK** part of `chars`.

Comment: I suppose that's why it shows "& s h y ;" in the code, but when you edit it, it doesn't show up

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, the weird thing is it seems I copy/pasted it from this page but can't make it show up here.

Comment: @Tim, Where/how did you see it as `&shy;` ?

Comment: Upon further inspection, IE9 shows the & s h y ; deal like in my screenshot. Firefox 4 and Chrome 13 do not.

Comment: Interesting. IE8 clearly shows `&shy;`, FireFox and Chrome hide it. Maybe we should add a HTML tag (:

Comment: I had actually started to response to the post saying that the string as I saw it (with the & and ; in it) could, theoretically, create & m d a s h ; or & n d a s h ; which might be part of the problem. But I figured there was no way you or Jon would have missed that :)

Comment: I needed to dig into  `byte[]` data from encodings to find it. Looks a little silly after you see it in IE